# removing .settings folder from eclipse project explorer view

Tags: eclipse, maven, settings, m2eclipse

When I started with eclipse with Mavenized project, I was not able to see the .settings folder.. But now when I open my project, .settings folder appears all the time.. Is there any settings or codes which needs to changed to hide this folder from the project explorer.

PS - It doesn't harm any program, but I think at the time of commit, it may create problem..

Adding screenshot for better clarification.[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the small triangle at the top right of the Project Explorer view and choose the 'Customize View' option.

In the dialog that appears check the '.* resources' filter to hide everything starting with '.' (there isn't anything to just hide .settings).

Comment: But this also hides useful files like .gitignore